# Factorial de un numero

Tags: java, factorial

Tengo un pequeño problema a la hora de calcular el factorial de un número. Estamos con todo el tema de funciones, metodos, etc. Y si me hace un poco dificil, tengo que calcular el factorial de un numero y mi código es el siguiente:

```
package factoriales;

import java.util.*;

public class factorialNumero {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.print(Factorial(25));

    }
    public static String Factorial (int n) {
        
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduzca el numero del que desea ver el factorial");
        n = teclado.nextInt();
        int producto;
        if (n==0) {
            return "No hay factorial";
        }
        if (n==0 || n==1) {
            return "1";
        }
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            producto = i * n;
        }
        return null;
        
    }
}
```

El problema está en que el programa no me devuelve nada porque tengo el "return null" pero si pongo cualquier otra cosa me salen un montón de errores. Espero que el error sea facil de corregir.
Un saludo, Jorge.

Comment: Dos cosas: Factorial de 0 es 1 y tu función debería devolver un número, no un string: te sobra el primer if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Por lo visto estás calculando el factorial de un número de forma iterativa.

> El máximo entero positivo representable en Java con el tipo `int` es `2147483647`, el cual es un número de 10 dígitos. Si queremos calcular el valor de `13!`, el resultado es 6227020800, el cual tiene 6 unidades de billón, ya se pasa por al menos 4 unidades de billón del máximo `int`.

> Alguien puede sugerir usar un tipo `long` cuyo máximo es `9223372036854775807`. Igual, si deseamos calcular el valor de `21!` el resultado es `51090942171709440000`, que tiene un dígito más. Por lo tanto usar un `long` solo nos permite calcular hasta 20!.

Aclarados estos asuntos, podemos implementar una solución a tu problema repasando lo que significa un número factorial y luego aplicando la lógica adecuada para que nuestro programa calcule números factoriales al menos hasta `12!` usando sólo variables de tipo `int`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Básicamente lo que deseamos es crear una estructura iterativa que permita multiplicar un valor varias veces, almacenando en cada iteración el resultado para multiplicarlo en la siguiente iteración.

Esto lo podemos lograr usando un bucle `for`, y como valores límites usaremos 2 y `n`, donde `n` es el valor del factorial que deseamos calcular. Por ejemplo si deseamos calcular el factorial de 7, escribimos el bucle así:

```java
int n = 7;
for(int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
  // ...
}
```

Ahora, que ya sabemos lo que vamos a iterar, vamos a iniciar el factorial en 1, ya que si `n` tomase los valores 0 o 1, el factorial de ambos es 1.

Por último, el factorial de un número es otro número, por lo tanto tu función debe devolver un valor numérico no una cadena, tal como la tienes actualmente.

Por definición, el valor de un factorial o la función factorial se define sobre valores positivos, por lo tanto es algo a tomar en cuenta al crear el programa.

Para calcular el factorial de forma iterativa, tomamos un valor incial: `1`, y vamos multiplicando por cada entero que siga al valor inicial hasta llegar a `n`. Por ejemplo:

```
1 * 2 * 3 * ... * n
```

En un bucle `for`, el iterador `i` tomará los valores desde `2` hasta `n` y podemos calcular el factorial acumulando en cada iteración el valor anterior multiplicado por el iterador:

```
factorial = factorial * i
```

En Java (como en otros lenguajes) podemos usar el operador de asignación directa de la operación: `*=`, con lo cual la línea anterior puede verse así:

```
factorial *= i
```

Tu función factorial podría verse así:

```java
public static int Factorial(int n) {
    int factorial = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
      factorial *= i;
    }
    return factorial;
  }
}
```

En esta función se itera desde 2 hasta `n`. En el caso de que `n` tomase un valor menor que 2, simplemente no se entra en el bucle y se devuelve el valor de la variable `factorial` que está inicializada en 1.

Como puedes ver, he sacado de la función la petición del número al usuario, ya que la función debe recibir este valor como argumento.

El código completo de tu programa podría verse así:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class factorialNumero {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Introduzca el numero del que desea ver el factorial: ");
    int num = teclado.nextInt();
    if(num < 0) {
      System.out.println("No se puede calcular factorial de un valor negativo.");
    } else {
      int resultado = Factorial(num);
      System.out.printf("El resultado es: %d\n", resultado);
    }
  }

  public static int Factorial(int n) {
    int factorial = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
      factorial *= i;
    }
    return factorial;
  }
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a comprender mejor el problema y las limitaciones a la hora de calcular un valor factorial con representaciones de tipo `int` o de tipo `long`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio me ha quedado todo bastante claro la verdad, una explicación buenísima de todo este tema que ya me ha quedado algo más claro, gracias, de verdad.